# Keep Variables Data even closing the apps

Tags: c#, data-persistence

I am new in C#, facing a problem right now.
Is there any other ways that I could store/keep my variables data even I exit my apps or until next start, beside than store the variables inside Properties > Settings ??

Comment: Database, text file, serialized class or collection are a few other options.  What is wrong with Settings?

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways of persistence of data in .NET

- [XML / JSON Serialisation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/182eeyhh(v=vs.110).aspx) (Good for storing objects - ie. complex
  data)
- [Registry keys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry(v=vs.110).aspx) (good for simple things like flags / states
  etc..)
- Simple text files (general purpose)
- Settings configs
- Databases...

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412179(v=vs.110).aspx